# GetWorldLinearVel animation problem

Tags: gazebo-6

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello everybody,

I am moving a box using the animation system (KeyFrame,...). I would like to output some datas like the model's position and speed. I have created a model plugin.

No problem for the position but I have some trouble for the speed.

The GetWorldLinearVel function seems to return a 0.0 value for x, y and z attributes.

Here is the code to get the speed datas :

```
custom_msgs::msg_command speed_msg;
speed_msg.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
speed_msg.header.frame_id = m_model->GetName();

auto linear = m_model->GetWorldLinearVel();
speed_msg.yaw_rate.data = m_model->GetWorldAngularVel().z;

ROS_INFO("speed data");
ROS_INFO("x: %lf", linear.x);
ROS_INFO("y: %lf", linear.y);
ROS_INFO("z: %lf", linear.z);
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/14356/getworldlinearvel-animation-problem/) by [Brosseau.F](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2389/brosseau.f/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 284 on 2016-09-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The animation framework is a cheat that bypasses the physics engine to move an object. A velocity is not applied to the object, instead the object's position is directly changed by Gazebo. Therefore, the physics engine will report a velocity of zero.

You could calculate a velocity manually in your program/plugin.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2016-09-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Brosseau.F](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2389/brosseau.f/) on 2016-09-08**:
Thanks to both of you

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I think that happens because when an entity is being animated, it is considered "static" by the physics engine. That is done so no forces interfere with the animation. So I would assume that the physics engine loses track of other things too, such as velocity.

A workaround would be to keep track of pose changes over time and calculate the velocity yourself.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2016-09-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1